# How to specify starting level of DDR Menu in DNN

Tags: xml, dotnetnuke, ddrmenu

**URL:** http://bit.ly/1Lqi1io

**Brief:** On the example URL I have a Static orange menu using the DNN HTML module. I would like to recreate this menu for all pages on the site so that the menu is dynamically updated from the CMS instead of having to be updated manually in the HTML.

The blue tree menu below it is the DDR Menu with TreeView template.

**Issue:** By default the menu/template is showing the main parent menu links with private markets highlighted as the active menu. I can't figure out how/where in the template to specify that this menu should do the following:

1. Start from the CHILD links (Private Equity and Real Assets) of the current Parent (Private Markets)
2. Show all CHILDREN of CHILDREN (Fund Offerings)

The existing template is located here: http://bit.ly/1MH2fgW

The [DDR Menu guide](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/wiki/ddrmenu-xslt-templates) doesn't comprehensively tell me how to create a template so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried using the NodeSelector option in the DDRMenu?

Answer (score 1):

You should spend some time reading the DNN Wiki pages related to the DDR menu.  That, coupled with some experimentation should give you a really good understanding of how it all works.

Use the module version of the DDR menu, and drop it on an empty page.  Then you can play around with the NodeSelector parameter to see how it determines which pages are shown.  Start with that empty and you should get all pages.  Move on from there.

I highly recommend using the ULTokens template for your explorations.  You'll get a nice UL showing the selected pages.

You can also use the DumpXml template to show exactly what is available to the templates.

Other attributes that are helpful are IncludeNodes and Exclude nodes.

I'n most cases, you won't need to create your own template.  Restyling ULTokens or SuperFish is often enough.  The MegaMenu template is also approachable.

I'm happy to answer other questions.

Comment: Thanks for that. Unfortunately I'm on a time crunch and this is the last piece to get a site production ready.

I have already tried everything in the documentation but whenever I add anything to the Node Expression to specify the starting level, the entire menu disappears.

Comment: If you take away the NodeSelector attribute, the menu should show the entire set of pages.

as for the time crunch, it shouldn't take more than a half-hour to an hour to figure this out.  We've been discussing this for a couple of days.